# What is the function of the (new Date()).getTime() in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I was looking at some javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log(time);
</script>
```

What is the function of (new Date()).getTime() in php?

because i want try to make it into php language , but with microtime() still different output with javascript. what should i do?

Comment: ya but there's many argument in time() ,  if u can check this functions in javascript new Date()  the ouput like 'Sat Dec 12 2015 22:44:26 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)'

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript `(new Date()).getTime()` returns the number of **milliseconds** since 1970/01/01.

If you want to make a porting to PHP you can use `time()*1000`.

> `time(void)` returns the current time measured in the number of **seconds** since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

In PHP you can multiply for 1000 the result of `time()` to achive the same behaviour of `(new Date()).getTime()` in JavaScript.

In your code you can write something like:

```
<?php
...
echo time()*1000;
...
?>
```

Note that PHP is executed server side and from there you can't access to the browser console.
If you want to literally port the script you've provided, you have to use a bit of JavaScript to print the result to the console.

You can take a look here:

- [PHP time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)
- [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `(new Date()).getTime()` prints out time from unix epoch in milliseconds. To achieve the same in PHP, you can simply do

```
<?php echo (int)(microtime(true)*1000); ?>
```

To get the equivalent value.

Answer (score 0):

[Time in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
$time_stamp = time();
echo $time_stamp;
```

Or

```
echo microtime(true)*1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `microtime()`.

```html
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log(time);
</script>
<?php
    $str = microtime();
    $pecah = explode(" ", $str);
    print $pecah[1];
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:    Strtotime('now');

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. Use php function:

`time();`

Example:

```
$t=time();  
echo $t;
```

You also can get time using:
`date("h:i:sa");`

Answer (score 0):

For higher precision, you may try this :

```
<?php echo round(microtime(true) * 1000); ?>
```